# Android detect ListView fling

Tags: android, listview

I'm wanting to add a listener to my ListView that would detect when a user has triggered a fling. I already have a scroll listener but wish to perform a background operation when the user decides to 'fling' away from their current position.

Thanks,
Laurence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try ListView's [`OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) and listen for `SCROLL_STATE_FLING`.

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
    if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
        // Control reaches here on fling
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that was it. Thought I was missing something simple, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Mock a action_down event to the target view:

```
view.dispatchTouchEvent(
MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), 
System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, 
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0));
```